# The name 'fileName' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, android

HI I m trying t build a sample android app which retrieves the file info of the file path provided here s the code

there are 2 .cs files wic i m using one is "mainactivity.cs" whose code is shown below

mainactivity.cs

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace ACCESSTIME
{

[Activity (Label = "ACCESSTIME", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    //int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        EditText filepathText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.FilePathText);
        Button getinfobutton = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.GetInfoButton);

        string fileinfo = string.Empty; 

        getinfobutton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
         {

            fileinfo = GetInfo.Main(filepathText.Text);
        };
     }
  }
}
```

and the other file is 
getinfo.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;


public static class GetInfo
{
public static string Main (string text)
{

    // Full file name 
    //string fileName = @"";
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);

    // Get File Name
    string justFileName = fi.Name;
    Console.WriteLine("File Name: {0}", justFileName);
    // Get file name with full path 
    string fullFileName = fi.FullName;
    Console.WriteLine("File Name: {0}", fullFileName);
    // Get file extension 
    string extn = fi.Extension;
    Console.WriteLine("File Extension: {0}", extn);
    // Get directory name 
    string directoryName = fi.DirectoryName;
    Console.WriteLine("Directory Name: {0}", directoryName);
    // File Exists ?
    bool exists = fi.Exists;
    Console.WriteLine("File Exists: {0}", exists);
    if (fi.Exists)
    {
        // Get file size
        long size = fi.Length;
        Console.WriteLine("File Size in Bytes: {0}", size);
        // File ReadOnly ?
        bool IsReadOnly = fi.IsReadOnly;
        Console.WriteLine("Is ReadOnly: {0}", IsReadOnly);
        // Creation, last access, and last write time 
        DateTime creationTime = fi.CreationTime;
        Console.WriteLine("Creation time: {0}", creationTime);
        DateTime accessTime = fi.LastAccessTime;
        Console.WriteLine("Last access time: {0}", accessTime);
        DateTime updatedTime = fi.LastWriteTime;
        Console.WriteLine("Last write time: {0}", updatedTime);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }       }
}
```

if i build this i m getting error as
"The name 'fileName' does not exist in the current context"

plz help me out

Comment: you are commenting it. `//string fileName = @"";`

Answer (score 0):

You are commenting the file name:

```
//string fileName = @"";
```

Secondly if you want the file name from command line then use:

```
public static string Main (string fileName)
{
  FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
```